# Let $f$ be continuous on $[-1,1]$, Show that $g_n \to f$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ be continuous on $[-1,1]$, Show that $g_n \to f$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$
where

$$
g_n(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}f(y)p_n(y - x)dy
$$

and

$$
p_n(x) = \frac{(1-x^2)^n}{\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx}
$$

I was trying to show that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x \in [-1,1]}|g_n - f| = 0
$$

I permute the sums and integral and use the binomial theorem. Also, I use the fact that $f$ is bounded (continuous on a compact set). After all of that, I could only get an upper bound for the sup. But I can not show that the bound goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$. There is a simpler approach? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I should use the Weierstrass M-Test, but I can not see how to bound the sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the idea here is that $p_n\geq 0$ is a very good approximation to the delta function meaning: for all $\delta>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{|y|>\delta}p_n(y)dy=0$, $\int p_n\equiv 1$ and $\sup_n\|p_n\|_{L^1}=1<+\infty$.

Now given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ so that $|x-y|\leq\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\varepsilon$ by uniform continuity of $f$. And choose $N$ so that $n>N\implies \int_{|y|>\delta}p_n(y)dy\leq\varepsilon$. Then,
\begin{align}
|g_n(x)-f(x)| &\leq \int_{-1}^1 |f(y-x)-f(x)|p_n(y)dy\\
&=\int_{0\leq|y|\leq\delta} |f(y-x)-f(x)|p_n(y)dy+\int_{1\geq|y|>\delta} |f(y-x)-f(x)|p_n(y)dy\\
&\leq\varepsilon\cdot\|p_n\|_{L^1}+2\|f\|_{\infty}\cdot\varepsilon\quad\text{(Holder's inequality)}\\
&=\varepsilon\cdot(1+2\|f\|_\infty).
\end{align}

Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary and the upper bound is independent of $x$, we are done.

Comment: Is there any direct approach without using this approximation? I was bounding the difference but I can not find upper bound independent of x. Also, I do not see how you can insert the f(x) inside the integral.

Comment: The reason you can insert $f(x)$ into the integral is because $\int p_n(y)dy =1$ so that $f(x) = f(x)\cdot 1 = \int f(x)p_n(y)dy$. I don't know how to prove it without using ideas similar to above -- it seems too messy too me. Perhaps someone else does.

Comment: I think we can say that $$|g_n(x) - f(x)| = |\int_{-1}^{1}f(y)p_n(y-x) - f(x)|$$ and then $$|\int_{-1}^{1}[f(y) - f(x)]p_n(y-x)dx| \leq \int_{-1}^{1}|f(x) - f(y)|p(y-x)dx \leq 2\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ using the fact that $p_n$ is positive (in $[-1,1]$), $f$ is uniformly continuous and the integral of $p_n$ is $1$. I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work, Richard. You need $x$ and $y$ to be close (hence the above $|x-y|\leq\delta$) if you want to conclude that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\varepsilon$.